# How to fix this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble getting this SQL statement to run in MySQL.

```
    SELECT c.cost_center_name as cost_center_name, COUNT(e.employee) as number_of_employees, SUM(e.w2_wages) as total_wages, c.qualified_percent, c.qualified_percent*SUM(e.w2_wages)*.01 as qualified_wages
    FROM cost_center as c, employees as e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e2 ON e.department=cost_center_name
    GROUP BY cost_center_name
```

I get the error
#1054 - Unknown column 'cost_center_name' in 'on clause'

Comment: You would need to group on the columns which are not part of the aggregate functions

Comment: You need to expose result of first select as a table and name it (say A), and then use A.cost_center_name in join ON clause.

Comment: Do not mix joins over `where` and over `join` clauses. You need to join `cost_center` and `employees`

Comment: Why do you cross join cost_cener and employees?

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit join syntax, way too confusing. Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Make it possible to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.cost_center_name as cost_center_name, 
       COUNT(e.employee) as number_of_employees, 
       SUM(e.w2_wages) as total_wages, 
       c.qualified_percent, 
       c.qualified_percent*SUM(e.w2_wages)*.01 as qualified_wages
FROM cost_center as c
CROSS JOIN employees as e
LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e2 ON e.department = c.cost_center_name
GROUP BY cost_center_name
```

---

What is the problem in initial query? The precedence.

Comma has lower priority then JOIN. So FROM clause is totally

```
FROM cost_center as c, (
                        employees as e
LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e2 ON e.department=cost_center_name
                        )
```

And when 2 `employees` copies are joined `cost_center_name` column which is posessed in `cost_center` table is not visible.

Comment: This will execute, but will the result make any sense?

Comment: @jarlh I cannot tell something about this. I simply remove logical error and explain its source.

Answer (score -2):

This should work

```
  SELECT c.cost_center_name as cost_center_name, COUNT(e.employee) as number_of_employees, SUM(e.w2_wages) as total_wages, c.qualified_percent, c.qualified_percent*SUM(e.w2_wages)*.01 as qualified_wages
    FROM cost_center as c, employees as e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e2 ON e.department=c.cost_center_name
    GROUP BY cost_center_name
```

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit join syntax, way too confusing. Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: And why do you put a table alias in `on`, but not in `where`?

Comment: Never mix implicit and explicit joins. Better yet, never use implicit joins.

Comment: Still _error #1054 - Unknown column 'cost_center_name' in 'on clause'_.

Comment: @jarlh can u please provide me ur scheme details

Comment: @MerajHussain see this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=7a2d1eb83c55e1da5a26d60727f4ad92